# Error al consumir Web Service de AFIP (constancia de inscripción)

Tags: webservice, asp.net-core, blazor

estoy conusmiendo el Web Service de AFIP (Argentina) para consultar la constancia de inscripción en blazor .net5. En Homologación/Testing funciona bien y me trae los resultados correctamente. El problema está en el entorno de Producción:

Implementación:

```
public async Task<personaReturn> GetConstanciaInscripcion(long cuit)
    {
        
        PersonaServiceA5Client persona = new PersonaServiceA5Client(PersonaServiceA5Client.EndpointConfiguration.PersonaServiceA5Port);
        var response = await persona.getPersona_v2Async(datosTA.Token, datosTA.Sign, autorizado, cuit);                        

        return response.personaReturn;
        
    }
```

En la página blazor llamo al método anterior incorporando el bloque `try/catch`

```
try
{
    var personaReturn = await _afip.GetConstanciaInscripcion(cliente.Cuit);

    cliente.RazonSocial = personaReturn.datosGenerales.razonSocial.ToUpper();
    cliente.Domicilio = personaReturn.datosGenerales.domicilioFiscal.direccion;

    await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("global.notificacion", "success", $"Datos cargados con éxito");


 }
catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Error.ProcessError(ex);//<-- aquí me arroja la excepción...
   await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("global.notificacion", "error", $"{ex.Message}");
 }
```

El error no me dice mucho, solo `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` . Esto ocurre cada vez que intento consumir el Web Service. Sólo una vez me dió un mejor detalle del error. Copio:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.

 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): Mensaje recibido inesperado, o bien su formato es incorrecto.

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)

   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

La App que hice corre en una red interna, por lo que el certificado SSL es el certificado por defecto que da el IIS. ¿Será ese el problema?. En la misma App consumo el Web Service de la Factura Electrónica, pero no me da ningún error, por lo que me respondo a la pregunta anterior.

Esta situación se escapa de mis conocimientos, por eso pido alguna ayuda para tratar de resolverlo.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Das por sentado que GetConstanciaInscripcion() siempre devuelve un resultado.

El error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` es propio de tu aplicación. Te recomendaría hacer algunas verificaciones antes de utilizar el resultado de GetConstanciaInscripcion() ya que si esta pinchando pero dentro de un bloque trycatch no te enterarias y devolveria null.

Algo asi:

```
var personaReturn = await _afip.GetConstanciaInscripcion(cliente.Cuit);
        if (personaReturn != null)
        {
            cliente.RazonSocial = personaReturn.datosGenerales.razonSocial.ToUpper();
            cliente.Domicilio = personaReturn.datosGenerales.domicilioFiscal.direccion;
        }
```

Una vez validado esto, deberias meterte en la funcion GetConstanciaInscripcion que es la que seguramente te de mas informacion sobre la exception que mostras

Comment: Gracias!, efectivamente estaba usando mal el bloque. Evidentemente mis ojos ya están cansados!!!

Comment: Buenas. Esta es una pregunta más general. Alguno sabe si existe un web service de afip específico para generar la constancia de inscripción en pdf? Agradecería la respuesta.